# How to use pandas apply function on rows without lambda?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-apply

I don't understand well how the `apply` function works.
Here's my code which works fine:

```
dftest = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['A BERTHOU'], 'b': ['BERTHOU']})

def test2(a, b):
      return a + b

dftest['concat'] = dftest.apply(lambda row: test2(row['a'], row['b']), axis=1)
```

But I want to do the same without using lambda function.
I tried this:

```
dftest['concat'] = dftest.apply(test2(dftest['a'], dftest['b']), axis=1)
```

and this

```
dftest['concat'] = dftest.apply(test2(dftest['a'].str, dftest['b'].str), axis=1)
```

But none works.

Can you tell me how to use my function without using lambda function?

A precision : I want to use complex function so

```
df['sum'] = df.col1 + df.col2 or 

dftest['concat'] = dftest[['a', 'b']].sum(axis=1)
```

wont' work.

I knew the solution

```
dftest['concat'] = dftest.apply(test2, axis=1)

def test2(row):
    return row.a + row.b
```

but I don't like it : it's impossible to undestand what is applied without looking to function (no parameter in the apply ligne) + the function is ugly : the function is not generic and tied to row.a and row.b

Conclusion : for the moment the best solution seems to be

```
dftest['concat'] = dftest.apply(lambda row: test2(row['a'], row['b']), axis=1)
```

and it seems imposssible to do it without the use of lambda on a complex function and using good coding pratices

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to do this instead:

```
dftest['concat'] = dftest.apply(test2,axis=1)
```

what it does is function `test2` is applied to each row.

```
def test2(row):
    return row.a + row.b
```

Comment: As pointed out in my answer, I'd avoid using lambda wherever it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
dftest['concat'] = dftest[['a', 'b']].sum(axis=1)
```

This will used the implemented vectorized colum/row oriented functions. I strongly recommend using these over any kind of fully written statements like `apply` or also `dftest['a'] + dftest['b']`, since only to fully optimized and vectorized backend of pandas will be used.

Furthermore try to avoid `apply` and `lambda` at all costs. `apply` will be orders of magnitudes slower than the implemented vectorized operations for larger DataFrames. Reasons why not to use `lambda` can be found in the PEP-8 styleguide (even though this is imho mainly based on personal preferences...)

For the case that you **really** want to use `apply` and `lambda` for some special reasons you can write your statement like this:

```
dftest['concat'] = dftest.apply(lambda row: row['a'] + row['b'], axis=1)
```

or this:

```
dftest['concat'] = dftest.apply(lambda row: row.sum(), axis=1)
```

Comment: You are welcome. But I recommend to accept an answer and to open up a follow up question for the *more complex function* that you added to your question. Otherwise it is highly unlikely that you'll get answer on this more complex question.

Answer (score 0):

To apply function with pandas :

df['new_col'] = function(df['old_col'])

```
>>> import pandas as pd 
>>> d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> print(df)
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4

>>> df['sum'] = df.col1 + df.col2
>>> print(df)
   col1  col2  sum
0     1     3    4
1     2     4    6
```